# It is a painting by / of a famous painter

Tags: prepositions

Could you please help me with this? A bit of context:

> Look at this painting. In the painting you can see a little girl. So, it is a painting **of** a girl. A famous painter painted it. So it is a painting ___ a famous painter.

I thought we should use "of" to show that the painting depicts the person, while "by" shows who painted it, but in the test it was "of" in both cases. Is "by" acceptable /correct or not in the latter case?.

Comment: I have been doing online tests recently and the quality is shockingly bad. Your analysis is correct.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In this case it is a painting _by_ a famous painter. If we spoke of 'a painting _of_ a famous painter' we would mean either 1. That the painter _owns_ the painting or 2. That the painting _depicts_ the painter. 'By' is an ablative expression. 'Of' is a genitive expresion.

Comment: @NigelJ If someone refer's to "a painting of Van Gogh", 99% of the time, it will be referring to a painting that depicts Van Gogh. There's far simpler and more unambiguous ways to phrase the possessive (like simply saying "Van Gogh's painting"). "Of" can be used to denote membership/ownership (the ides of March, the Queen of England), but in this particular case, using "of" for that purpose will likely be misunderstood. "By" is absolutely the better choice here.

Comment: @NuclearWang I agree with what you are saying but one must allow for the 1% (if that is, indeed, an accurate figure), because it is both grammatically and semantically correct.

Comment: I feel a subtle difference between giving the name of the painter or just a general statement:

This is a painting **of** a famous painter.

This is a painting **by** Vincent van Gogh.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily answered by example.

This is a painting *by* [Vincent van Gogh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh):

[image]

This is a painting *of* Vincent van Gogh<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

This is a painting both *by* and *of* Vincent van Gogh:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> If we allow paint as a verb to refer to MS Paint rather than oils etc. Some "artistic" licence is needed.